# How adjust "Maximum upload size" indicator for file upload?

Tags: form, form-fields-types, file-upload

Joomla prints a short notice regarding the *Maximum upload size* when including a file upload field with the standard form field `file`, see code and image below:

```
<field
    name="image"
    type="file"
    label="COM_EXAMPLE_PICTURE_LABEL"
    description="COM_EXAMPLE_PICTURE_DESC" 
    accept="image/*"
/>
<field
    name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
    type="hidden"
    default="2097152"
/>
```

[image]

The Joomla docs for [file](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/File_form_field_type) mentions adding a hidden field to set the maximum file size. It's not entirely clear if Joomla does anything with that field or if all the logic needs to implemented in the controller (e.g. in the `save` method).

> You can put a soft limit file size by adding a hidden field with name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" and value the maximum allowed bytes which is handled by php, but you must also handle it in your code with or without it.

However, that wouldn't change the way the field is displayed. Is there a way to show a different maximum file size?

It looks like that message is set in `layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php`:

```
...

$maxSize = JHtml::_('number.bytes', JUtility::getMaxUploadSize());

...

    <?php echo JText::sprintf('JGLOBAL_MAXIMUM_UPLOAD_SIZE_LIMIT', $maxSize); ?>
```

**PS**: I don't what to change the `upload_max_filesize` for PHP in the `php.ini`, just for this particular form.

### Update

Using the approach suggested by [Lodder](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28663/how-adjust-maximum-upload-size-indicator-for-file-upload/28667#28667), I added a file `components/com_YOURCOMP/layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php` to my component and copied the content  of `layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php`. Then I replaced the line

```
$maxSize = JHtml::_('number.bytes', JUtility::getMaxUploadSize());
```

by

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_file(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/forms/add-form.xml');

$fieldMaxSize = $xmlData->xpath('//field[@name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"]');

if (isset($fieldMaxSize[0]['default']) && !empty($fieldMaxSize[0]['default'])) 
{
    $sizeValue = $fieldMaxSize[0]['default'];
} 
else 
{
    $sizeValue = JUtility::getMaxUploadSize();
}
$maxSize = JHtml::_('number.bytes', $sizeValue);
```

Comment: You will have to handle the max upload size yourself. You'll also need to override that layout if you wish to change or remove the text

Comment: I do already handle the max upload size in the save method of the controller, that works (I was just wondering if anything is already implemented that I missed). I'm looking for the proper way to change that one line (or the value of `$maxSize`). Do I need to set up a custom form field?

Comment: You'll need to override this layout `layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I already guessed that I somehow have to override that layout, hence I mentioned it in the question. But I do not know what the appropriate way is to accomplish that. With `FieldsHelper::render` (like mentioned [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Overrides))? I didn't get it to work.

Comment: I'd like to change the output for the field in this one form, not for all `file` fields nor would I like to alter the template (since this is specific to the component, not site wide)

Comment: Copy `layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php` to `components/com_YOURCOMP/layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php`. Or if it's for the form in the administrator part of your component, then `administrator/components/com_YOURCOMP/layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php`.
Overriding this layout will apply for ALL **file** fields, but only those that are part of **your** component.
If you genuinly need this change for a single file field in your component (assuming you're using this file multiple times), then you'll need to create a custom field

Comment: That worked like a charm! Would you like to add this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to perform this override for all **file** form fields only within your component, then you can override the layout at component level.

To do this copy the following layout:

> layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php

to:

> components/com_YOURCOMP/layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php

If the form field reside in the administrator views, then copy the layout to:

> administrator/components/com_YOURCOMP/layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php

Once done, you can make the necessary changes to the layout without it affecting the visual aspects anywhere else on the site.